# Excel sometimes won't calculate a cell

Tags: excel, calculation

I have an odd situation where an XL sheet sometimes does not update the value after a cell is changed. And yes, Automatic calc is on!
The formala is just a simple one, eg. =A1*B1. And it will work most of the time.
But then I change some values, eg A1 or B1, and notice a glaring error in the sheet. If I then click on A1 or B1 and enter again, the sheet updates and continues to behave.
But then after a while, I notice it's done it again. Not always the same cells.

XL version Office 2021 Pro

I though there may be a glitch in the sheet, so tried deleting the sheet, copying the values and formulae to a new one, but same issue.

I've not seen it on any other sheets. ** I have now seen it on other sheets also! ** Damn! :-(

Anyone seen anything like this? Or have any ideas?

Comment: Often I find saving, closing then restarting Excel helps.

Comment: Do you have macros running, either on your workbook or as an addin library? If yes, can you look for `ScreenUpdating` and `EnableEvents`; and `Calculation` just in the case it gets changed then restored without your knowledge?

Comment: No, this happens every time I open this sheet.

Comment: It's just done it again. Changed a cell value, and nothing updates. Selected another cell, still nothing. Press Enter - Updates.  Weird!

Comment: Ah! Managed to reproduce the issue and notice that the "Calculate" prompt is showing bottom left. Yet checking calculation options shows Automatic. I enter a value in another non-related cell and it calculates!

Comment: And again. This time no "Calculate" prompt showing! ???

Comment: ** I have now seen it on other sheets also! ** Damn! :-(  I think it might be when I've entered a number and clicked away too quickly.

Comment: If you have a circular reference then automatic calculation will pause until you resolve it.

Comment: Right... looks like Atmo was on the righ track (thanks!). I disabled macros and it no longer does it. Re-enable them, and it's back. Will look to see what may be in macros to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by have macros enabled. No idea why. I have used Excel with macros enabled for decades and never seen this issue before.
Have checked my macros and there's nothing that could cause this.
Can only conclude that it's an issue that's been added by a recent update from microsoft.

Will take it up with them and report back in the unlikely event of getting any sense out of them!